# Accented characters in gnuplot qt terminal

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, gnuplot

I've been trying to produce a gnuplot image as a training exercise. I am unable to produce accented characters. Here's what my configuration looks like:

```
            G N U P L O T   
    Version 5.0 patchlevel 3    
last modified 2016-02-21 
terminal type is qt 0 enhanced font "LiberationSans,12" 
fontpath is 
            system fontpath is 
"/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts"  
gnuplot LC_CTYPE pt_BR.UTF-8    
gnuplot encoding   utf8
gnuplot LC_TIME    pt_BR.utf8
gnuplot LC_NUMERIC C
```

If I type something like

```
set title "Órgão"; plot sin(x);
```

In the terminal it show

```
set title "\U+FFC3rg\U+FFC3\U+FFA3o"
```

The resulting plot simply excludes all accented characters. I've even tried using the "svg terminal" to no avail.

Comment: The reason might be the same as in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346179/umlauts-in-gnuplot-command-line)

Comment: @maij It worked. I set an alias as instructed and it solved my problem just fine.