# Umlauts in gnuplot command line

Tags: character-encoding, gnuplot, diacritics

I want to plot surface data in gnuplot (I'm new with gnuplot and found nothing in the docs or via google that worked). It works pretty ok for the beginning with `Splot "heightfield.dat"`.

The problem I have is the path to the file. It contains Umlauts (contains a `Ü`). I can not change into this folder with `cd` or plot with a path like this. Of course I just changed the Ü to a U to work, but this is kind of a dirty hack.

The problem is that I can not even type it. When I type `Ü` it is replaced with `\U+FFC3`. I tried to `set encoding utf8` and others, but nothing worked. It seems only affect the plots and diagrams.

So I want to be able to type umlauts in the gnuplot command line as naturally as possible. Is there a solution to this?

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using gnuplot 5.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same problem exist on Debian Jessie. It seems that it only appears in the interactive mode, reading commands containing umlauts from a file works as expected.

According to [this Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnuplot/+bug/1068815) the reason is that the gnuplot executable is linked against libedit instead of libreadline due to licensing issues. There they also link the [reason](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=608442#25) that it is legal to work around this issue by running gnuplot from the commandline as

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 gnuplot
```

Depending on how you start the program you might want to put this command into an alias or something similar.

Comment: Or you can configure and build gnuplot with the option "--with-readline=gnu".

Comment: To build it yourself, see list of -dev packages necessary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526044/installing-gnuplot-5-0-on-ubuntu/31819448#31819448

Comment: Thank you both, this solved it. Btw, I saw that linuxbrew provides a version that uses libreadline by default. Unfortunately I did not manage it to install/compile with qt (without investing some time), so I'll use an alias or so for now.